# Caching using @Cacheable with Spring MongoDB integration in spring boot and redis

Tags: redis, spring-cache, spring-mongodb

I was wondering if it's possible to use @Cacheable annotations on the spring data mongo repositories.  For example like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    @Cacheable("byId")
    public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
        User findById(String id);
    }
}
```

I'd like to do it on the interface class itself and avoid having a wrapper class if possible.  In addition, is there a sample for how to do the cache config for redis with java config (not xml)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `Cacheable` on any public method with spring aspects. You also have to use `EnableCaching` in any configuration class and optionally a `CacheManager` bean.